# AttributeError caused by existing attribute

Tags: django, pylibmc

I *sometimes* get the following errors when my django app tries to get from or store something in the cache:

```
    c = cache.get(pk)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 131, in __getattr__
    return getattr(caches[DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS], name)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    cache = _create_cache(alias)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 88, in _create_cache
    return backend_cls(location, params)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 185, in __init__
    value_not_found_exception=pylibmc.NotFound)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NotFound'
```

but why? the module has the attribute, and most of the time it works, there is no file with the same name that can break this, where to look for the cause of this?

```
>>> import pylibmc
>>> pylibmc.NotFound
<class '_pylibmc.NotFound'>
>>>
```

Comment: This could most likely be a bug. You could [file an issue](http://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/issues) on their GitHub repo.

Comment: other possible explanations, your cache timed out and emptied, returning an empty object, or you used the same 'pk' to store a different object by mistake somewhere in your code.  check your code where you add cache.set and see.

Comment: Can you show your `CACHES` from the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** try importing pylibmc at an application startup location, such as the `uwsgi` or `manage.py` file.

My *guess* is that it's a multithreading issue while importing `pylibmc` in a request thread inside [`PyLibMCCache.__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py#L182) as opposed to at application startup. *(IMO Django does the import there because not all Django installations use `pylibmc`, and thus they shouldn't force it on each app as a dependency)*

While *I'm not familiar enough with the internals of how `import`ing  works*, I suspect what happens is something like the below

1. thread #1 tries to import `pylibmc`
2. thread #1 places a placeholder in `sys.modules` for `pylibmc`
3. thread #2 tries to import `pylibmc` `->`  the `AttributeError` is raised
4. thread #1 finished updating `sys.modules` and now `pylibmc.NotFound` is available

In general, Python seem to [discourage runtime loading of modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.LazyLoader) as opposed to startup time loading.

*emphasis is mine*

> Note: For projects where startup time is critical, this class [`importlib.util.LazyLoader`] allows for potentially minimizing the cost of loading a module if it is never used. For projects where startup time is not essential then use of this class is heavily discouraged **due to error messages created during loading being postponed and thus occurring out of context**.